# Overloading Operator parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, operators, overloading

I was wondering how many parameters can an overloaded operator take in C++?

I've seen operators take both one and two parameters, so I wanted to know if they can take both or just one, specifically for the `-` and `<<` operators.

Comment: `<<` - No. That would be syntax error. `-` -  yes, [there is an unary minus operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155275/how-to-overload-unary-minus-operator-in-c).

Comment: .. Actually, [Is it possible to overload operator associativity in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21445933/2564301) has a better answer: "Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax specified in Clause 5."

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` always takes one parameter. E.g. with `x << y`, `x` would be the instance `operator<<()` is called from and `y` would be its parameter. Of course, you could overload the operator with different **types** of `y`, but always only one.

The `-` operator has two flavors, and is indeed overloaded with different number of arguments:

1. Unary (`-x`)
2. Binary (`x - y`)

Answer (score 0):

For the minus operator, it can only take one parameter like so:

```
object& operator-(const object &ref); //please note the syntax and use of const
```

For the << operator (called ostream), you overload it like so, it takes two parameters:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &str, const object &ref);
```

Hope that answers your question.